# Action does not trigger a reducer in React + Redux

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm working on a react-redux app and for some reason the action I call does not reach the reducer (in which I currently only have a log statement). I have attached the code I feel is relevant and any contributions would be highly appreciated.

Action called within function in component:

```
onSearchPressed() {
    console.log('search pressed');
    this.props.addToSaved();
}
```

actions/index.js:

```
var actions = exports = module.exports

exports.ADD_SAVED = "ADD_SAVED";

exports.addToSaved = function addToSaved() {
  console.log('got to ADD_SAVED step 2');
  return {
    type: actions.ADD_SAVED
  }
}
```

reducers/items.js:

```
const {
  ADD_SAVED
} = require('../actions/index')

const initialState = {
    savedList: []
}

module.exports = function items(state = initialState, action) {
    let list

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_SAVED:
            console.log('GOT to Step 3');
            return state;
        default:
            console.log('got to default');
            return state;
    }
}
```

reducers/index.js:

```
const { combineReducers } = require('redux')
const items = require('./items')

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  items: items
})

module.exports = rootReducer
```

store/configure-store.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from '../reducers'

let store = createStore(rootReducer)
```

EDIT: Entire component for onSearchPressed:

```
class MainView extends Component {
    onSearchPressed() {
        this.props.addToSaved();
    }
    render() {
        console.log('MainView clicked');
        var property = this.props.property;

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image style={styles.image}
                    source={{uri: property.img_url}} />
                <Text style={styles.description}>{property.summary}</Text>
                <TouchableHighlight style = {styles.button}
                        onPress={this.onSearchPressed.bind(this)}
                        underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
                        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Save</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = MainView;
```

Comment: check console.log(this.props) on onSearchPressed() and be sure that it's not null

Comment: @QoP console.log(this.props) is correctly populated.

Comment: that's weird! try to change exports.addToSaved = function addToSaved(){} to exports.addToSaved = function (){}

Comment: @QoP still only reaching the action log statement, and not the reducer log statement :\

Comment: can you provide the whole component where you are using onSearchPressed()?

Comment: @QoP just edited post to include this.

Comment: I think that you forgot to add the redux connector in order to connect your component with your redux state

Comment: You're not dispatching your action. `this.props.addToSaved();` should be `this.props.dispatch(addToSaved());`

Comment: Like @RickJolly said, your addToSaved  function is an `action creator` you have not dispatched this action, you have not fed it into the redux state machine so to speak.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Rick Jolly mentioned in the comments on your question, your `onSearchPressed()` function isn't actually dispatching that action, because `addToSaved()` simply returns an action object - it doesn't dispatch anything.

If you want to dispatch actions from a component, you should use [react-redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux) to connect your component(s) to redux. For example:

```
const { connect } = require('react-redux')

class MainView extends Component {
  onSearchPressed() {
    this.props.dispatchAddToSaved();
  }
  render() {...}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    dispatchAddToSaved: () => dispatch(addToSaved())
  }
}

module.exports = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MainView)
```

See the ['Usage With React' section of the Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) for more information.

Answer (score 9):

Recently I faced issue like this and found that I had used action import but it has to come from props. Check out all uses of toggleAddContactModal. In my case I had missed toggleAddContactModal from destructuring statement which caused this issue.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Modal from 'react-modal'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {
  fetchContacts,
  addContact,
  toggleAddContactModal
} from '../../modules/contacts'
import ContactList from "../../components/contactList";

Modal.setAppElement('#root')

class Contacts extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchContacts();
  }
  render(){
    const {fetchContacts, isFetching, contacts, 
      error, isAdding, addContact, isRegisterModalOpen,
      toggleAddContactModal} = this.props;
    let firstName;
    let lastName;
    const handleAddContact = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (!firstName.value.trim() || !lastName.value.trim()) {
        return
      }
      addContact({ firstName : firstName.value, lastName: lastName.value});
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Contacts</h1>
        <div>
          <button onClick={fetchContacts} disabled={isFetching}>
            Get contacts
          </button>
          <button onClick={toggleAddContactModal}>
            Add contact
          </button>
        </div>
        <Modal isOpen={isRegisterModalOpen} onRequestClose={toggleAddContactModal}>
          <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" ref={node =>         
 (firstName = node)} ></input>
      <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" ref={node => 
(lastName = node)} ></input>
          <button onClick={handleAddContact} disabled={isAdding}>
            Save
          </button>
        </Modal>
        <p>{error}</p>
        <p>Total {contacts.length} contacts</p>
        <div>
          <ContactList contacts={contacts} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = ({ contactInfo }) => {
  console.log(contactInfo)
  return ({
    isAdding: contactInfo.isAdding,
    error: contactInfo.error,
    contacts: contactInfo.contacts,
    isFetching: contactInfo.isFetching,
    isRegisterModalOpen: contactInfo.isRegisterModalOpen
  });
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      fetchContacts,
      addContact,
      toggleAddContactModal
    },
    dispatch
  )

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Contacts)
```

Comment: I had the same thing a few times and it's annoying as it just fails silently.

Comment: when a grown my is almost in tears... destructuring issues, after hours of debugging.

Comment: Thanks so much. This immensely helped!