# Redux: mapStateToProps is not being called

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I understand this kind of question was already asked several times here at StackOverflow. But I tried all the recommended solutions and nothing works for me. I'm running out of ideas.

The problem is with a React Native application for Android. Basically, the app provides a search bar to search an underlying database. The search results should be put into the store.

I use `Redux v4.0.5`, `React-Redux v7.1.3`, `React v16.12.0` and `React Native v0.61.5`. For debugging, I use `React Native Debugger` in the latest version.

Now the simplified code. First, the component with the search bar. Here, `mapStateToProps()` is called. User makes an input and `useEffect()` immediately runs the database query, which should result in immediately calling `mapStateToProps()`.

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';    
import {RootState} from '../../../rootReducer/rootReducer';
import {setResultValueSearchBar} from '../../../store/searchBar/actions';
imports ...

type Props = {};

const SearchBar: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const [returnValue, setReturnValue] = useState('');
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // get query results
    // logic to finally get a result string that should be put into the store
    const resultNames: string = resultNamesArray.toString();

    // method to set local and Redux state
    const sendReturnValueToReduxStore = (resultNames: string) => {
      setReturnValue(resultNames);
      setResultValueSearchBar({resultValue: resultNames});
      console.log('result value sent to store ', resultNames);
    };

    // call above method
    sendReturnValueToReduxStore(resultNames);
  }, [inputValue, returnValue]);

  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView>
        <Header searchBar>
          <Item>
            <Input
              placeholder="Search"
              onChangeText={text => setInputValue(text)}
              value={inputValue}
            />
          </Item>
        </Header>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

function mapStateToProps(state: RootState) {
  console.log("map state to props!", state); // is only called one time, initially
  return {
    resultValue: state.searchBarResult.resultValue,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setResultValueSearchBar,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

Here is the `rootReducer`:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

import searchBarResultReducer from '../store/searchBar/reducers';
import reducer2 from '../store/reducer2example/reducers';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  searchBarResult: searchBarResultReducer,
  reducer2Result: reducer2,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

Here is the `searchBarResultReducer` in `reducers.ts` file:

```
import {
  SearchBarResultState,
  SET_RESULT_VALUE_SEARCHBAR,
  ResultValueType,
} from './types';

const initialState: SearchBarResultState = {
  resultValue: 'No results',
};

// take state and action and then return a new state
function searchBarResultReducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: ResultValueType,
): SearchBarResultState {
  console.log('invoked result: ', action.type); // called only initially
  if (action.type === 'SET_RESULT_VALUE_SEARCHBAR') {
    return {
      ...state,
      ...action.payload,
    };
  } else {
    return state;
  }
}

export default searchBarResultReducer;
```

And the corresponding `types.ts` ...

```
export const SET_RESULT_VALUE_SEARCHBAR = 'SET_RESULT_VALUE_SEARCHBAR';

export interface SearchBarResultState {
  resultValue: string;
}

interface ResultValueAction {
  type: typeof SET_RESULT_VALUE_SEARCHBAR;
  payload: SearchBarResultState;
}

export type ResultValueType = ResultValueAction
```

... and the `actions.ts`:

```
import {SET_RESULT_VALUE_SEARCHBAR, ResultValueType, SearchBarResultState} from './types'

export const setResultValueSearchBar = (resultValue: SearchBarResultState): ResultValueType => ({
  type: SET_RESULT_VALUE_SEARCHBAR,
  payload: resultValue,
});
```

And `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import rootReducer from './src/rootReducer/rootReducer';
import Realm from 'realm';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import invariant from 'redux-immutable-state-invariant';

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({});
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer, 
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(invariant()))
  );

const Root = () => {
  Realm.copyBundledRealmFiles();
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Root);
```

To summarize: Whenever the database query succeeds, the result value should be sent to the store. But in the `React Native Debugger/Redux Devtools`, the reducer/`mapStateToProps()` is called only once and only, as shown by the console.log s in the code.

What is going on here?

Comment: From glancing over the code I do not see where you are getting `resultNamesArray` and `inputValue` in the first code sample. Could you please clarify ?

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan Thanks for your reply. `resultNamesArray`is generated in the logic after the query. Because it is so much code, I left it out. `inputValue` comes from the user input and is set in `useState()`, please see the updated code :)

Comment: When you type into the input does `sendReturnValueToReduxStore` get called ?

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan Yes, it gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! As stated by Hemant in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794236/action-does-not-trigger-a-reducer-in-react-redux) Thread, you also have to pass the action that you import as props into the component. Works like a charm now :)

Comment: so you had to call this.props. setResultValueSearchBar() ? You were not getting an error calling a non existing function before the fix ?

Comment: Yes. And also blind of me not noticing it. Good job though

Comment: You were such a great help! Thanks a lot :)