# Typescript and Redux: Binding element 'string' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript, redux

In my React Native application for Android, I have a component that uses `Redux`.

As stated by "Hemant" in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794236/action-does-not-trigger-a-reducer-in-react-redux) Thread, I have to pass the action that is imported as `props` into the component, too. Now I try to type the action correctly, but it gives me the error: `Binding element 'string' implicitly has an 'any' type` and I don't understand why.

Here is the code:

```
imports ...
import {reduxAction} from '../../../store/searchBar/actions';

type Props = {
  reduxAction: ({value: string}) => void;
};

const SearchBar: React.FC<Props> = ({reduxAction}) => { 

// calling the action method
const sendNamesToReduxStore = (names: string) => {
  // ... some other logic
  // calling the action method
  reduxAction({value: names});
};
```

As you can see, when calling the action method, `names` is declared as `string`. Therefore, I declare it as `string` in `Props`, too. I thought this was absolutely right. Please note: When I do `reduxAction: ({value: any}) => void;` it gives the same error as above with `any`: `Binding element 'any' implicitly has an 'any' type`.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else struggles with this problem:

You have to declare the type of the variable in your function with the type stated in the action.

```
reduxAction: (value: reduxActionState) => void;
```

... because in `actions.ts` I declared

```
export const reduxAction = (value: reduxActionState): ResultValueType => ({
  type: SET_RESULT_VALUE,
  payload: value,
});
```